# How to force FrameTicks labels to be nonlinear?

Tags: plotting, labeling, ticks

I want to make a color bar with nonlinear scale , with code

```
DensityPlot[v, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 1, 5}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{1, Red}, {2, Green}, {3, Blue}, {4, Yellow}, {5, Orange}}, #] &), AspectRatio -> 10, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 25, FrameTicks -> {None, Automatic}, FrameLabel -> None]
```

I get the result

[image]

How to replace 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 labels with other labels e.g. 3, 9, 27, 81, 243?

Comment: Have you tried Ticks option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Manual `FrameTicks` solution

In your specific example an easy way you can get the desired result by specifying the `FrameTicks` manually like this:

```
FrameTicks -> {{{{1, 3}, {2, 9}, {3, 27}, {4, 81}, {5, 243}}, None}, {None, None}}
```

[image: New FrameTicks]

#### `ScalingFunction` with automatic `FrameTicks` solution

If the coordinate value to screen mapping you want to show itself is not linear, starting with V12 you can also use `ScalingFunction` in most plot functions. In your example you could e.g. do it like this:

```
DensityPlot[v, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 3, 243},
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{1, Red}, {2, Green}, {3, Blue}, {4, Yellow}, {5, Orange}}, Log[3, #]] &),
  AspectRatio -> 10, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 25, FrameLabel -> None,
  ScalingFunctions -> {None, {Log[3, #] &, 3^# &}},
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {None, None}}
]
```

[image: Automatic FrameTicks and ScalingFunction]

Notice that we didn't have to manually specify the `FrameTicks`, they were generated for us, and that the `ColorFunction` now needs to be nonlinear, too.